# Animation in jQuery with play/previous/next

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using jQuery to animate and want different "scenes" so people can click on play the whole animation, previous or next scene, also jumping to a specific scene.

I wonder what the best way to do this is.

It seems that you can put animations in a queue in jQuery. Is that for animations like this?

Comment: something like this http://sixrevisions.com/demo/slideshow/final.html

Comment: No I don't mean a slider but animations using animate().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try jQuery plugin **[Camera slideshow](http://www.pixedelic.com/plugins/camera/)**. There is an option to embed online videos in it. You may create a thumbnail and use it for scene selection / navigation. Or you may go through **[70+ Awesome jQuery Slider Plugins](http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2012/08/jquery-slider.html)** and pick one for you. Some sliders support HTML content on their slides and not just images.

Comment: I think I am going to end up with a slider instead of raw animation. So I'll mark this one as the correct answer.